# Perl, set variable to entire command line 'string' rather than arguments

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, argv

I need to allow users to type in just about anything when they run my perl script as my script is sending all data to another non-custom script at different increments.

In theory, I'm hoping this could happen:

```
perlscript "this is" -t stuff\n4^./q%
```

Then, in perlscript, have:

```
print "Full: $full_command";
```

which results in:

```
Full: "this is" -t stuff\n4^./q%
```

That make any sense? Nothing I've tried yet does exactly what I'm looking for with argv or the like.

Thanks for any help,
Tim

Comment: Shell parses command-line, and then runs perl script with parsed one.  There is no way to know original command-line from perl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell does something equivalent to

```
exec('perlscript', 'this is', '-t', 'stuff'.chr(0x0A).'4&^./q%');
```

There's no way `perl` can produce the original shell command from that. If you want Perl to receive

```
"this is" -t stuff\n4^./q%
```

you need to tell the shell that using something like

```
perlscript '"this is" -t stuff\n4^./q%'
```

(Well, at least for a Borne shell or derivative.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your shell is likely to manipulate your arguments before they even get to the Perl script. In your specific example, a shell like bash would remove the quote marks, treat the `\n` as an `n`, and stop processing the line once it got to `&`. In Unixy systems, your best bet may be to wrap all of your arguments in single quotes

```
perlscript '"this is" -t stuff\n4&^./q%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you quote correctly for your OS, as mentioned above, perhaps the following will work for you:

```
print join(" ", map { / / ? "\"$_\"" : $_ } @ARGV);
```

Note that when you run perl you need to separate the arguments that are destined for perl itself from those for your program using the "--" token.  For example:

```
perl -- -t 'stuff...'
```

That will protect against arguments being mistakenly consumed by perl itself.

Comment: Your `print` does not produce the requested output for the given example. And the second half of your answer doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: How is the second part not relevant?  OP specified that he wanted the user to "type in just about anything".  Doesn't he need to prevent perl from interpreting user input as perl arguments?

Comment: @schtever The argument specifying script name will prevent perl from interpreting any further arguments as options for the perl interpreter.

Comment: @qqx I see.  I was thinking about a one liner when I wrote that, e.g. perl -e'join(...)' "$@".  Hence my concern about mixing user input into the argument list.  If the script is in its own file, then it doesn't matter, as you said.  Thanks for the explanation.